# What is the origin of the Portuguese word "joaninha" for the insect known in English as the "ladybird"?

Tags: etimologia

The coccinellid family of insects are known in British English as "ladybirds", in reference to the Virgin Mary who is also referred to in names used in a number of other languages. In Portuguese a popular name for these insects is "joaninhas".

What is the origin of this name?

Comment: Really good question. I'm looking forward to seeing the answer.

Comment: According to a text in the magazine Língua Portuguesa (Volume 2, Edition 26), the origin is unknown (see [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22conhecido+em+portugu%C3%AAs+como+%22joaninha%22%22&tbm=bks)). Unfortunately, it seems that the complete text is not available online

Comment: @Pedro, editei o teu link para o reduzir e de lá tirar as informações de tracking, modelo, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I think its etymology is lost in time! It is cognate with galician *xoaniña*. Someone (galician-portuguese) probably thought it was a good idea to call the insect "Little Joanne".

Comment: +1 for spotting the cognate, and because it's with Galician-Portuguese.